# Set vertex position

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, windows-forms

Can anyone tell me how to set the positions of model vertices? I want to be able to change the position of some of the vertices of a Model. Is there any way to make that happen? And make the changed visible at that moment.

---

**EDIT:**
Well, the thing is,I have a model, a cube, that is made up of four "thin" cubes(top,bottom,left side, right side), so I get this cube with "hole" in the middle. And I want to scale it on **Y** axis. If I do `Scale(0,2,0)` it will scale the whole object meaning, it will double the **Y** size of left and right side, but also double the size of the top and bottom cube, which I do not want. Same for **X** axis I want to double the size of top and bottom cubes but not the left and right one.

Hope you can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally don't want to manipulate the vertices of the model objects to move them around in your world.

Instead, you set the world transformation matrix (that you pass to [Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.model.draw.aspx)) accordingly, for example setting it to a [translation matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195697.aspx) that moves the model by the desired amount.

That said, if you really want to manipulate the vertices directly -- perhaps because you only need a subset to change, or infrequently, you can iterate the Parts collection of the Meshes collection of the model. Each mesh part has a vertex (and index) buffer object you can use to update the model.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you want to move *some* vertices...

Assuming you do simply want to move the vertices in object space, you would need to reupload them to the graphics card (however XNA handles this).

Or else apply a transformation to a particular *set* of vertices (eg. if you are moving an arm or a leg). That would require some method of identifying only those vertices which are intended to move, in your shader code... this can be done using vertex IDs, possibly.